# Implementing Queue in Java but cannot override the iterator() method

Tags: java, collections, iterator, queue, singly-linked-list

I am trying to develop my knowledge of the Queue interface by implementing it in my own "MyQueue" class. However, I want to override the iterator() method. Since I can't implement both the Iterator and Queue interfaces at the same time, I am at a loss.

On my iterator() method Eclipse is giving me the error, `cannot convert from MyQueue<E>.QueueIterator to Iterator<E>` when I mouse over the red underline below the words `new QueueIterator()`.

Also, when I try to implement my "QueueIterator" inner class, Eclipse gives me the error, `syntax error on token "class", @ expected` when I mouse over the red underline below the word `class`.

In the code examples below, I have removed all methods that have nothing to do with my question. I know I have to implement these methods to implement Queue. I'm just trying to make the problem clearer.

*How can I override the iterator() method?*

**MyQueue class:**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * A custom queue class. Uses a singly-linked list.
 */
public class MyQueue<E> implements Queue {
   // the top of the queue
   private Node<E> first;
   private int size;

   /**
    * Creates new myQueue object
    */
   public MyQueue() {
      first = null;
      current = null;
      size = 0;
   }

   @Override
   public Iterator<E> iterator() {
      return new QueueIterator();
   }

  /**
   * Holds Objects and points to the next one.
   *
   */
  private class Node<E> {
     private E data;
     private Node<E> next;

     /**
      * Creates a Node object
      * @param data The Object to be held by the Node
      */
     Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
     }

     private Node<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
     }

     private E getData() {
        return this.data;
     }
  }

  /**
   * Iterator implementation
   */
  private class QueueIterator() {

     private Node<E> curNode;

     public QueueIterator() {
        curNode = null;
     }

     public boolean hasNext() {
        if(curNode == null && first != null) {
           return true;
        } else if (curNode.getNext() != null) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
     }

     public E next() {
        if(curNode == null && first != null) {
           curNode = first;
           return curNode.getData();
        }

        if(!hasNext()) {
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        curNode = curNode.getNext();
        return curNode.getData();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueueIterator` needs to implement `Iterator<E>`.

You shouldn't have the parentheses on this line:

```
  private class QueueIterator() {
```

It should be just:

```
  private class QueueIterator {
```

Actually:

```
  private class QueueIterator implements Iterator<E> {
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like forgetting to get rid of the parentheses gave me a bunch of weird errors. I will accept your answer in 6 minutes or so.